# CDI injection of beans with no scope

Tags: java, cdi

We have a CDI project using:

- Tomee Container
- Apache OpenWebBeans for CDI
- Deltaspike CDI extensions

In the `beans.xml` file of the webapp the discovery mode is configured to the recommended setting: `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"`.  Despite this I am able to inject this class, which isn't annotated with a scope:

```
public class TestClass implements Serializable {
    public String getDescription() {
        return "This is a test class";
    }
}
```

Into this `ViewScoped` class without any issues:

```
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class AuthenticationWebBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private TestClass testClass;
```

I would have expected this to either throw an exception, or to leave the field as null.  What is happening here, and will the injected `Object` take the same scope as the `object` it's injected into?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `TestClass` enjoys the default CDI scope which is `@Dependent` which will be created every time it is requested (it is not necessarily an HTTP request only). A proxy is injected at the injection point which may be a different instance on every request. (The instance of `TestClass` at the injection point could be different from what it was at its creation time as the injected instance is not a real instance - it is a fake instance called a proxy).  What is the functional requirement?

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks for the information.  The reason I'm asking is because we saw a massive memory leak when the javax.faces library was included in the webapp lib rather than the Tomee lib, every page that was requested resulted in loads of Faces objects being created in the WebContext and never released.  I suspected it was a side effect of the behaviour I mentioned above, now I know about @Dependent scope it makes sense!  Moving the faces lib solved the memory leak.

Comment: You could use the bare `javax.enterprise.inject.Typed` annotation on a bean to prevent it from being registered as a CDI managed bean. "*When a [`@Typed`](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.1/javax/enterprise/inject/Typed.html) annotation is specified, only the types whose classes are explicitly listed using the `value` member, along with `Object`, are bean types of the bean.*"

Comment: Thanks for you help Tiny!

Comment: @Tiny Why do you think TestClass gets `@Dependent` scope? Bean discovery mode is set to "annotated" so this bean should not be fount at all with "unsatisfied dependencies" error message. It does not work as it is supposed to do.

Comment: Please indicate what version of TomEE you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're describing is in CDI 1.1/1.2, Java EE 7 compliant containers would follow it.

You're using TomEE 1.7.2, which is Java EE 6/CDI 1.0 compliant.  It's going to operate under the rules of CDI 1.0 which makes everything a CDI component.

TomEE 7 would begin to demonstrate the behavior you're describing.

Comment: But will TomEE 7 ever be released? Or will it be like Geronimo that just stopped although they never said they stopped?

Comment: Its under active development.  Feel free to swing by the mailing list, say hi.

Comment: @john.ament Would be cool if the team was a bit more communicative about it. Some time ago they said early 2015 after being pushed a little and that was already a bit late. But now we're near the end of 2015 and it's a question whether 2015 will even be an option.

Comment: @john.ament p.s. of course TomEE/Apache is under no obligation in any way to deliver sooner or later, so if it's 2016 then it's 2016, but just the occasional blog or tweet about progress and target dates would be great ;)

Answer (score 2):

TomEE normally supports only Java EE 6, only night builds support Java EE 7. `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` is only supported in Java EE 7. It means that in TomEE it is most probably ignored and then all beans are considered for injection. If you want to exclude a bean from injection, annotate it with `@Alternative`. Otherwise the bean would be injected with the same scope as the bean it is injected into. This is equivalent to `@Dependent` scope, which is default.